# Need to limit access to a mobile website to specific registered mobile devices

Tags: mobile, security

I've researched a ton and can't seem to find a solution for how to limit access to a secure mobile website to ONLY PREVIOUSLY REGISTERED devices.

I already have a secure login in-place, but we must also insure that ONLY registered devices access the site.  We cannot have users sharing login information with others and allowing others to login and use the protected information.

Is there anyway to do this?

I've looked at trying to acquire the devices MAC address using JavaScript, PHP, or something similar, but this doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: Bump because I just ran into this requirement and am hopeful someone can provide some insight.

Answer (score 0):

MAC addresses can be [spoofed](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/how-to-spoof-a-mac-address/395), so use something else such as [REST-based authentication](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/iphone-tutorial-authenticating-with-a-restful-service-using-nsurlcredential/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that because websites usually register users as opposed to their mobile devices as nothing can be truly unique about a physical device but the information it carries. The proper way of doing client based (as opposed to user based) authentication is to use a client certificate.

If you just want to simplify the sign-in experience for your users on mobile device you may want to take a look at [this](https://readysignon.com/).