# Allow only registered mobile devices access to a web app

Tags: authentication, web-applications, mobile

I have a requirement to allow mobile devices access to a website only after those devices have been registered, is there anyway I can get any kind of device information through javascript that would match up to a registered user or registered device **without entering a password everytime someone wants to use the site**.

I was hoping to register the IMEI number and have it passed to me in the mobile browser, but obviously I can't have that.

Security isn't really the biggest deal in this situation, convienance is, and someone taking enough time to spoof the system is not something I care about.

Comment: I could, but cookies seem so unstable. I don't mind having a bit of an instensive registration process to get the cookie on there, but I would need to set it to not expire like a native app 'cookie' or a cert or something. I don't want the user to go through the registration process everytime the cookie expires.

Comment: This question lowers my hope that there will be an answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955855/need-to-limit-access-to-a-mobile-website-to-specific-registered-mobile-devices

Comment: I think there's an answer for you -- you're looking for convenience, not National Security.  What's wrong with a cookie that has a 4 year expiration?  Every time the user connects you can always reset the expiration to "now plus 4 years".